# Locating footer at the left side of the page (flexbox)

Tags: html, css

I am stuck!
I am trying to locate the footer at the left side of the page. But footer is limited to 1200px. If I change the maximum width to 1500px, my #Mission section gets shifted. 
Is there way to make footer 1500px, while not shifting #Mission at all?
Here is a link to my [index.html](https://github.com/vtka/my_times/blob/master/tea_cozy/index.html)
And here is my [styles.css](https://github.com/vtka/my_times/blob/master/tea_cozy/resources/css/styles.css)

Comment: post all of your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed closing `</div>` tag on [line 90](https://github.com/vtka/my_times/blob/master/tea_cozy/index.html#L90) so your `<footer>` jumps inside outer `.main` container. Maybe it somehow related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the missing tags. But problem was fixed after adding margin: auto; to #Mission and width: 1400px; to the footer.